# Azure ServiceBus can't be imported in raspberry pi

Tags: python, azure

I've installed Azure for Raspberry wizzy. But, when following code example http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-python-how-to-use-queues/ I'v tried to test the very first line of code:

```
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusService, Message, Queue
```

I got error:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo python IoT_Acc/cgateway/azure.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "IoT_Acc/cgateway/azure.py", line 2, in <module>
    from azure.servicebus import *
  File "/home/pi/IoT_Acc/cgateway/azure.py", line 2, in <module>
    from azure.servicebus import *
ImportError: No module named servicebus
```

However I have azure installed with servicebus module:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ls -lah /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/servicebus/
total 164K
drwxr-sr-x 2 root staff 4.0K Mar 22 22:31 .
drwxr-sr-x 6 root staff 4.0K Mar 22 22:31 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff  33K Mar 22 22:31 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff  27K Mar 22 22:31 __init__.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff  48K Mar 22 22:31 servicebusservice.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff  42K Mar 22 22:31 servicebusservice.pyc
```

Do anyone knows what the issue is here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have named your file  `"/home/pi/IoT_Acc/cgateway/azure.py"` so you are importing from that not that module. Rename your file and make sure to delete the `azure.pyc` file also.

Comment: Great! Thank you. It was my case. :)

Comment: @user3484210, no worries, it is an easy mistake to make.